# MySQL: Query for selecting unique patients

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck with a query not returning unique records.

I have following tables:

```
clinics (id => PK)
patients (id => PK, clinic_id => FK)
patient_visits(id => PK, patient_id => FK, clinic_id => FK)
```

A patient is registered to a clinic. A patient can visit to any clinic any number of times.
What I want is to return all unique patients who visited in a clinic.

I tried following query which is not returning unique records for a clinic

```
SELECT v.id
     , v.patient_id
     , v.clinic_id
     , c.name clinic_name
     , p.name
     , p.mobile
     , p.email
     , p.gender
     , p.created_at
     , last_visit_date
     , visit_count 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT patient_id
                     , clinic_id 
                  FROM patient_visits
     ) pat
  JOIN patient_visits v
    ON pat.patient_id = v.patient_id 
  JOIN clinics c
    ON c.id = v.clinic_id 
  JOIN patients p
    ON p.id = v.clinic_id 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT patient_id
            , MAX(patient_visits.created_at) last_visit_date
            , COUNT(patient_visits.created_at) visit_count 
         FROM patient_visits 
        GROUP 
           BY patient_id
     ) visits_aggregate 
    ON visits_aggregate.patient_id = p.id 
 WHERE v.clinic_id = ? 
 ORDER 
    BY visit_date
```

One problem I understand is if I join with patient_visits, it will pick matching duplicate patient_id, clinic_id combination.

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You should refrain from JOINing to all the rows in `patients_visits` as it will cause the notorious combinatorial explosion leading to duplicate rows. You need an aggregate.

But, your example showed `patient_visits.id`. If you don't want duplicates in your result set for each visit, you cannot show that column; it has a different value for each visit.

You need an aggregate from the patient_visits table, like this:

```
               SELECT patient_id, clinic_id, 
                      MAX(created_at) last_visit_date,
                      COUNT(*) visit_count
                 FROM patient_visits
                GROUP BY patient_id, clinic_id
```

That query contains one row per combination of patient and clinic, so you can JOIN it to your other tables without generating duplicate rows. Before you do that, run it separately to convince yourself it works correctly.

Then... use it in your query like this

```
select patients.id patient_id, clinics.id clinic_id, 
       clinics.name as clinic_name, 
       patients.name, patients.mobile, patients.email, patients.gender, 
       patients.created_at, 
       pv.last_visit_date, pv.visit_count
  from patients
  join (       SELECT patient_id, clinic_id, 
                      MAX(created_at) last_visit_date,
                      COUNT(*) visit_count
                 FROM patient_visits
                GROUP BY patient_id, clinic_id
       ) pv ON patients.id = pv.patient_id
  join clinics ON pv.clinic_id = clinics.id
 order by pv.last_visit_date
```

See how this works? You don't want all the visits, just an aggregate of them giving the date of the most recent one and the count.

Answer (score 0):

I don't realy understand your complex query. Your Query should be straight forward:

```
select 
 pv.patient_id,
 pv.clinic_id,
 max(pv.visit) as last_visit,
 count(*) as visit_count
from 
 patient_visit pv,
 patients p
 -- You may now here join the other tables
where 
 pv.patients_id = p.id
 and pv.clinic_id = ?
group by
 pv.patient_id
```

As I see this, your use of distinct is in the inner select. And you are selecting patient_visit twice creating a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of the table getting all combinations.